# How to create PDF with repeating table header?

Tags: ios, pdf

[image]

Top two table and middle table header repeating in every page in PDF.

Comment: Hey @gpG there is no library available in iOS for PDF, you need to do it your self with custom code.

Comment: Something like add the check if its new page then add required header text. then continue remaining text.

Comment: @Mind_Sparkles How to make a cell with innertable like as shown image ?Please help with some code